# Forbidden (403) error when accessing server-info on apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I'm getting Forbidden error when trying to access www.website.com/server-status

mod_info is enabled

The VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.website.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/roastandbrew
        <Location /server-info>
                SetHandler server-status
                Order allow, deny
                Allow from all #just for testing 
        </Location>

        <Directory /var/www/roastandbrew>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I get this error in error.log :

```
 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/roastandbrew/server-info
```

Thanks